# Add custom loot from c++ code in Azerothcore

Tags: c++, module, azerothcore

im trying to create a new module; for this, i need add a custom handler to general loot. i.e: add a loot item for every monster in the world,  not by sql.

im actualy edit this files:

in LootMgr.cpp:, inside LootTemplate::Process, i added a new call of a new method created by me:

```
sScriptMgr->OnBeforeLoot(loot, store, lootMode, player, groupId);
```

inside of OnBeforeLoot, execute some code and then, i want add a item on loot like this:

```
LootStoreItem* storeItem = new LootStoreItem(ITEM_ID, 0, 100, false, 1, 0, 1, 1);
 loot.AddItem(*storeItem);
```

---

the item is showing in the loot of some monster in the world, but i cant loot them.

and only is showing in the first monster. then the next monsters dont loot NOTHING.

do you know how i can correct insert a custom item in a loot without using the loot_template table? only by code

Thank you!!!

Comment: Unrelated (probably): Allocating an object with `new` an then storing it  with a dereference as in `loot.AddItem(*storeItem);` sets the memory leak alarm bells ringing. Need to see more code on this to know if it really is a bad idea or not, though.

Comment: ok great, thats probably is a problem. im actualy newbie in c++. thank you for your answer

Comment: Id try the same code without "new" but using another ítem id (a existent item) and it works! The problem is probably in db